# Is good performance/high score rewarded somehow?

Tags: strike-suit-zero

At the end of a mission, the game gives the player a fairly detailed report of how they did, tallying up points and filling some sort of meter. Does the player get any rewards for excelling in some area or getting a high score?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: how's the game?  I've been wondering if its worth picking up

Comment: @spartacus it's like Freelancer (the controls, in particular, are very similar) with prettier graphics and everything but combat removed and, for some reason, you're flying a transformer, though a few missions put you into fighters/interceptors/bombers. I wouldn't spend more than $5 on it.

Comment: hrm, is it open exploration like freelancer?

Comment: @spartacus no, it really is just combat. Sometimes you fly from one battle to another for about 30 seconds.

Comment: darn, I got super excited when you mentioned Freelancer like :P  I'll still get this game at some point, but like you said, probably when its under 5$

Comment: @spartacus I heard Galaxy on Fire was a lot like Freelancer. X3 games are like a cross between Freelancer and EVE, you can fly alone or with a dozen capital ships supported by your military-industrial complex. Squadron 42 should be good when it comes out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I've completely reversed this answer. There *is* one reward that has a significant effect.

A high score on a mission earns you a better [medal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/114391/how-do-i-earn-medals). There's a bit of text in the mission debriefing that tells you what effect you had on the Colonial fleet. If you earn a Silver medal or worse, your feeble efforts aren't enough to slow down the enemy. If you earn a Gold or Platinum medal, you've done something effective to the Colonials: either they had to divert ships from their main attack on Earth to defend against your raids, or you successfully defended some Earth base with minimal losses, or something else that means you're being a very sharp thorn in the Colonial forces' side.

**Once you have enough Gold or Platinum medals, you get the better ending.** (You'll probably get the bad ending the first time around; it's much, *much* easier to get gold medals on the early missions once you have the Strike Suit and/or better weapons. The ending doesn't change much, but the epilogue is different.) It takes more than 6 Gold medals; I finished the game with 6 gold/platinum and got the bad ending, and then finished it again with 9 gold/platinum medals and got the good ending.

There are no other rewards: you get better medals, better bragging rights for high scores, and nothing else. You can get ship upgrades by completing side objectives, but that's unrelated to your score for the mission.